# jQuery fade not working in IE

Tags: jquery, fade, fadeto

http://bit.ly/Veyy5

If you view the above URL in FireFox and try to change any of the search parameters you'll see that the search results portion of the page fades to a low opacity and then fades back in once the results are received. In IE this doesn't fade at all. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284163/jquery-ie-fadein-and-fadeout-opacity) resolve your bug? Are you using PNG's for transparency (IE7 [bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/04/26/412263.aspx))?

Comment: Hi Sergi,

There are no PNGs used at all in this page. Maybe I'll try setting the opacity and a background color (white) to see if that helps. Thanks for the advice!