# jQuery Cycle - IE not loads the image at once (blinking occurs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cycle

I'm having problem with jQuery Cycle plugin in IE8 (and other IEs as well)

I have 3 slides which contains Title, Description + Image.

The problem is that in IE8 the image is "blinking" / not loading at once (the bottom is cut off for a while is it displayed fully).

Before I had problem with the white BG under the slider, but I fixed that with  cleartype: true, cleartypeNoBg: true, however with or without these the blinking occured as well.

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the fading of pngs. See some of these other posts for ideas on how to handle it:

[jQuery fadeIn IE Png Issue when loading from external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808015/jquery-fadein-ie-png-issue-when-loading-from-external)

[jquery cycle IE7 transparent png problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985/jquery-cycle-ie7-transparent-png-problem)