# Internet Explorer cannot perform image opacity animation correctly

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have tested my website on all browsers and it works fine:
http://bgsorken.com/sandbox/index.php
Besides Internet Explorer 8 (and probably earlier versions). It works fine on IE9. On the main page if you look at the "watch trailer" player image, it has an opacity animation on mouseover. Somehow on IE8 this looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/47R3k.png

and animates to pitch black.

I have literally grown a few grey hair today because of this and now relying on the community here to potentially guide me to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this thread on Google.
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?590295-jQuery-fadein-fadeout-of-transparent-png-in-IE7-and-Chrome

This is one of the solutions talked about there:

```
.item img {
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */   
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
zoom: 1;

}
```

Some people are also reporting that Unit's PNG fixe solves the issue.
http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however can you kindly elaborate on how I can add this fix? More details would be appreciated.

Comment: I would try adding this css to img.bigFrameplaybutton.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't seem to work. Can you kindly look at my stylesheet under bigframeplaybutton and see if I added it correctly?

Comment: It sure does look like you added it to the right place. Right now I don't have any more ideas, sorry!

Comment: That is fine, thank you regardless. Hopefully someone else will assist me.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808015/jquery-fadein-ie-png-issue-when-loading-from-external

Comment: It did partly - I have decided to add a <!--[if IE]> tag in there and remove the animation for IE users. Honestly, I would rather bring a worse experience for users of IE than to give a better presentation of my website. I have been programming independantly for years now and I always seem to have some type of issue with IE. Especially the period when adjusting for IE6 was current, God shot me in the head I despise Internet Explorer. I will give this answer as correct for your efforts.

Comment: Thanks! I think you made a good decision there, grading down the experience for users with old browser forcing them to upgrade.