# Issues with $.getJSON in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8

I'm unfortunately required to support IE8 and I'm unable to get even a simple `$.getJSON` request to work properly.

Here is the code:

```
url = "http://www.somejson.com/data.json";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var funds = []; var benchmarks = [];
    funds.push(data.funds); benchmarks.push(data.benchmarks);

    $.each( data.funds, function(key, value) {

        var ticker = key;

        // Monthly:
        var appendToDaily = function(ticker) {
            $.each($("#"+ticker), function(key, value, index) {
                $(this).children("td").filter(":nth-child(1)").html( '<td>'+funds[0][ticker].name+'</td>' );
                $(this).children("td").filter(":nth-child(2)").html( '<td>'+ticker+'</td>' );
                $(this).children("td").filter(":nth-child(3)").html( '<td>'+funds[0][ticker].fund.inception_date+'</td>' );
            });
        };

        appendToDaily(ticker);

    });

});
```

This code works just fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9+.

I've tried a few things to fix this with no success:

- I've tried to use the `$.ajax` method instead.
- Set the header for the JSON data to: `response.setContentType("text/javascript; charset=UTF-8");` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517608/why-isnt-this-simple-bit-of-jquery-getjson-working-in-ie8).
- Added this snippet before the `$.getJSON`: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` then reset it to true just before terminating the call as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264216/getjson-returning-cached-data-in-ie8).
- I've explicitly included `json2.js` just in case.
- Reverted to JQuery `1.11.0.min.js` just in case.

When I attempt to run this code, I get several errors saying that "fund" and "funds" are undefined. I also notice that absolutely nothing inside the `$.getJSON` callback function fires; even an `alert()` is ignored.

I'm kind of at my wit's end here so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if Javascript is enabled in IE8 or other security settings that's preventing the script from running -- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/howtoscript

Comment: Hrm, JS seems to be enabled; no issues there. Good thought though, I'm sure it's going to be something small and easily missed like that.  -_-

Comment: Step 1: figure out why it isn't working. Look to your console, even IE8 has one. Know what the problem is before you start trying to blindly "fix" it.

Comment: Is this a JSON request, or is it a jsonp request.

Comment: It's JSON. I have been looking at the console, all it says is "fund is undefined" and "funds is undefined".

Comment: Try adding `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`. That will tell you what's coming back from the server. You can then check that for the `funds` property you are trying to access. Note that `JSON.stringify` is defined in json2, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be getting a successful response if your data is undefined. Try using the following snippet to see if you can isolate the error.

```
$.getJSON('http://...')
     .done(function(response) { console.log('complete'); })
     .fail(function(error) { console.log('error'); });
```

If the console outputs 'error' you can work from there.  You can either step-debug or output the error result to the console.

Comment: `.error` is incorrect, you should be using `.fail`. `.success` and `.error` were deprecated in 1.8

Comment: Additionally, in the error callback, you should be logging the 2nd and 3rd arguments aswell. the are text status and error message generated by jquery.

Comment: Thanks Kevin B, you're absolutely correct.  I've been working on a project that's still on jQuery 1.7 for the past 3 months and 'error' was just on my mind.