# Fading with jquery in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Im using fade in/out jquery on my site but it doesnt work in IE,

```
banners[0].fadeOut(1000, "linear");
banners[1].fadeIn(1000, "linear");
```

banners is an array with my elements in.

Ive checked other posts such as

[jquery IE Fadein and Fadeout Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284163/jquery-ie-fadein-and-fadeout-opacity)

Tried all of the suggestions such as setting the filter but no luck. My elements are positioned absolute too.

My fading images are not transparent, they are just jpegs

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of IE? 8 and below have horrible opacity support and I'd actually abandon hope of getting it working flawlessly on those.

Comment: IE 8 and IE7 no IE6 fortunatly

Comment: Have you tried using banners[0].fadeTo(1000,0) instead? This works a bit better in my experience...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you shuld try different approach by adding different classes to your banners and NOT using array?
Or try selecting it by index something like:

```
  $('.banners').index()===1{
   //do something...
  }
```

Or maybe even if statment

```
 if($(".banners")[0] == $(".banners")[0])
 { 
 //do something
 }
```

Check this fiddle on IE : http://jsfiddle.net/FUMDW/