# opacity in IE8 not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have set opacity for a overlay which is working fine in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE9 but not in IE8. I googled alot but did not find any solution.

my css code is

```
#overlayEffectDiv { 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.50;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3000;
    /* hide it by default */
    display: none;
}
```

In FF it is looking as below:

[image]

but in IE8 it is looking as below:

[image]

Comment: Have you read that **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8 ??**

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `-ms-filter`. The latter can only be used in IE9 and up.

Comment: @MrLister shouldn't `filter` work only in IE7 (and older)?

Comment: Hey check to this url and know about opacity http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Comment: using jquery fade effects for example breaks the filter, maybe you should search in this direction....

Comment: @Adriano I can't seem to find the correct MSDN page for `filter`, but here's one mozilla page that says IE8 uses `filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity

Comment: @MrLister you're right, they're synonyms! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Adriano Oh... you mean I was wrong, they're synonyms! The OP's syntax was correct after all.

Comment: @MrLister not really, we were both wrong...I thought filter wasn't supported in IE8! LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284163/jquery-ie-fadein-and-fadeout-opacity). Opacity was not the problem I did some debugging and found it was working fine for ie8 the issue was with jquery fadeIn and fadeOut. jQuery fadeIn was making translucent background to turn solid.

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you syntax for the filter is correct:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/02/19/the-css-corner-using-filters-in-ie8.aspx

this might not be the cause of the problem but it might be worth ruling it out.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have define `zoom` also. write like this:

```
#overlayEffectDiv { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    opacity: 0.50;
    *zoom:1;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3000;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs for some animation effect involving the layer, you could avoid use `filter` at all in IE and use instead as a repeated background a small (not too small, like 2x2, use e.g. 100x100) transparent `png` file with a black background color and ~80% opacity