# jQuery fadeTo not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a div fading in using `fadeTo`. It works great in Firefox and IE9. It does not work in IE8. Here is my code:

**JS**:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    window.onload = function(){ 
    $j('#fadein').fadeTo(6000, 1, function() {
  });       
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-center" id="fadein" style="opacity:0;">
<img src="src.jpg" alt="Text" class="feature-image" />
</div>
```

How do I get this to work in IE8?  I do not mind changing from `fadeTo` to `fadeIn` or some other method of fading in a `div` as long as it works in IE8.

Comment: Why on earth would you use window.onload ?

Comment: @adeneo - I have a GIF animation loading above the div fading in and I want that fully loaded before the script fires. I am open to different or better methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284163/jquery-ie-fadein-and-fadeout-opacity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's fadeTo() should work in IE8, however the element has to have "layout", see this on "[haslayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)", and the CSS syntax for opacity in crappy browsers are :

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue. I thought it may be something like that. But I could not remember the correct code!