# jquery opacity in fadein not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, opacity, fadein

I am very new at putting J query stuff in my project.
I have one section here, by clicking on the image one pop-up box appears with background faded.
I have use the below written code :

```
<style>     
    #overlaynew{
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         top:0px;
         background-color:#000;          
                     opacity: .75; /* standard: ff gt 1.5, opera, safari */
                     -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)”; 
                     filter: alpha(opacity=50);
                     -khtml-opacity: .75; /* safari 1.x */
                      -moz-opacity: .75; /* ff lt 1.5, netscape */

         position:fixed; 
         /*z-index:1000;*/
         display:none;
    }
</style>

<script>
function showboxlogin(id)
{
    $('#overlaynew').fadeIn( 2000, function(){ $('#minilogindiv').show();   
     });        
}
function hideboxlogin(id)   
   {

    $('#minilogindiv').fadeOut( 2000, function(){ $('#overlaynew').hide(); });
}
</script>
```

Its working perfectly in Firefox, while clicking the background faded and the popup appears.

> Blockquote

But in IE8 the background get dark/black completely.
Could it be possible to make the IE8 effect same as firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Post a fiddle or working example if you can

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [jquery IE Fadein and Fadeout Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284163/jquery-ie-fadein-and-fadeout-opacity)

Change your `showboxlogin` function to the following:

```
function showboxlogin(id)
{
    $('#overlaynew').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=50)');
    $('#overlaynew').fadeIn( 2000, function(){ $('#minilogindiv').show(); });        
}
```